# Why are my flexbox properties disturbing my hr tag?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, divider

So I am making a sidebar with my code and want there to be a divider between some elements, to achieve that I used the hr tag but it behaves unexpectedly when I use it in my contextual code.

When I first added the hr element it didn't show up at all there was just alot of extra space between the places which I added them hence the image-
So I went on codepen and isolated the issue to find out which element exactly was tampering with this very simple tag. I slowly took my CSS styling properties away and waited for a dramatic change to see which one was making the hr tag behave weirdly.

I found that it was my flexbox properties in my sidebar div class and I found that it was my display:flex properties this was my layout

```
sidebar{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: space-between;
```

All my properties tampered with it in some way when to take you through what happens
*normal sidebar everything ok but I want to tweak the layout the hr tag is already there and functioning normally*

I add display flex, as the default is not the vertical cross axis it makes my sidebar go horizontal the hr tag is still there

When I add flex-direction column the layout goes back to vertical but all my hr tags have gone and are now there's a blank white space where there supposed to be

When I add justify content space between it gives me my desired layout but there are spaces between where I have added my hr dividers and its just now showing up

Here is my minimal reproducible example for the code

```css
.sidebar{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height:709px;
 width:634px;
 margin:0.5px;
 padding:10px;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
   <header class="title"> x's habit cloud</header>
  
        <ul>
          <div class="sidebar">
          

   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>search</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i>settings</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-inbox"></i>updates</a></li>
   <hr>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-note-sticky"></i>+add a page</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>my home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>notes</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen "></i>journal</a></li>
   <hr>
```

From the example you can see that if you remove the styling the hr tags come back

And if you cannot interact with the code to see it without the styling feel free to use my CXodepen link https://codepen.io/Adama-J/pen/GRzdapy to go ahead and interact with my code in any way seems fit to determine the issue from diffirent angles

If anyone has any insights or recommendations to solve this issue that would be warmly appreciated!

Image of what I want my hr to look like and where I want it to be
[image: There is no actual hr tag]

Answer (score 2):

- **First** you should avoid using `div` under `ul`.
- **Secondly** you should use `hr` under list item to make symmetry in your
  HTML structure

Here is your updated `HTML` & `CSS`

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
  margin-bottom:1.5rem;
  background:gray;
  padding:10px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0;
}

.sidebar li {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
}
.sidebar li a{
  padding:10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<header class="title"> x's habit cloud</header>
<ul class="sidebar">
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>search</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i>settings</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-inbox"></i>updates</a></li>
    <li><hr></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-note-sticky"></i>+add a page</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>my home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>notes</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen "></i>journal</a></li>
   <li><hr></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you  wrapping my hr element in the li worked I didn't even have to change anything else may I ask why ?

Comment: As I told, you can not any other html element directly to any type of list item. <li> tag is the direct child of any list(ordered/unordered).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest then that if you want groups in your menu/sidebar you use the appropriate elements, submenus for instance.

Then use borders and margin/padding to create separation.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 50vw;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: .5em;
}

li a{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
  padding: .25em 0;
}

i {
margin-right: .5em;
}

ul ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

ul ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="sidebar">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>search</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i>settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-inbox"></i>updates</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-note-sticky"></i>+add a page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>my home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-bookmark"></i>notes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen "></i>journal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you don't mind could you explain this code and how to use sub menus? I have done some research on sub menus but everything Ive read has further confused @Paulie_D